# Split dataframe by the value of an 'id' index inside a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I want to split my dataframe by incrementing the 'id' feature inside a for loop, **the following code is wrong**, but it's useful to understand what I need to do:

```
for i in range(1, len(test_set)+1):
       test_group = test_set.groupby('id' = i)
```

Actually my dataframe is composed by:

```
id freq   zreal     zimag        z      vout

3,4641.6,0.01973,-0.0026217,0.0098557,0.46996
3,2154.4,0.020439,-0.00056634,0.0098625,0.46893
3,1000,0.021008,0.00056902,0.010099,0.4679
...
5,10,0.025125,0.0048403,0.023461,0.61891
5,4.6416,0.027424,0.0030767,0.025226,0.61885
5,2.1544,0.02854,0.0018009,0.026065,0.61879
...
6,4.6416,0.025321,0.0029805,0.024945,0.63063
6,2.1544,0.026252,0.0017602,0.025696,0.63048
6,1,0.026665,0.00079044,0.02607,0.63033
... etc
```

every cycle I need to have 'test_set' dataframe with different 'id':

first cycle, test_set:

```
1,4641.6,0.01973,-0.0026217,0.0098557,0.46996
1,2154.4,0.020439,-0.00056634,0.0098625,0.46893
1,1000,0.021008,0.00056902,0.010099,0.4679
```

second cycle, test_set:

```
2,4.6416,0.025321,0.0029805,0.024945,0.63063
2,2.1544,0.026252,0.0017602,0.025696,0.63048
2,1,0.026665,0.00079044,0.02607,0.63033
```

and so on.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve], it is unclear from your question what you want to produce.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you properly, you can get this done as so:

```
a=list(set(test_set['ID']))  # This will store all unique IDs into list 'a'
cnt=1
for i in a:
    locals()["df"+str(cnt)] = test_set[test_set['ID'] == i ] 
    cnt +=1
```

**Explanation:**

Assume you had 3 IDs in your dataframe - 3,5 and 6. You want to create 3 dataframes based on these ids - df1 (having data of ID=3), df2(having data of ID=5), df3(having data of ID=6).

For this, I first created a list of unique IDs. I also initialized a counter (cnt=1). Then, i split the dataframes into individual dataframes based on the ID value inside a 'for' loop.

At the end of the loop, you will have 3 dataframes (or as many dataframes as there are unique IDs) containing the necessary data.

**Example:**

test_set:

```
    ID  freq        zreal        zimag      z           vout
 0  3   4641.6000   0.019730    -0.002622   0.009856    0.46996
 1  3   2154.4000   0.020439    -0.000566   0.009862    0.46893
 2  5   10.0000     0.025125    0.004840    0.023461    0.61891
 3  6   4.6416      0.025321    0.002981    0.024945    0.63063
```

After running the loop:

df1:

```
    ID      freq    zreal        zimag        z         vout
0   3       4641.6  0.019730    -0.002622   0.009856    0.46996
1   3       2154.4  0.020439    -0.000566   0.009862    0.46893
```

df2:

```
    ID      freq      zreal       zimag      z          vout
2   5       10.0      0.025125    0.00484   0.023461    0.61891
```

df3:

```
    ID      freq        zreal       zimag       z           vout
3   6       4.6416      0.025321    0.002981    0.024945    0.63063
```